# php avoid special characters in the output of openssl_encrypt and base64_encode

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, openssl, cryptography

I have written the following PHP code which is returning **/**, **+** and **=** in the cipher text. If I pass these values in url then **/** and **+** may create problems. **/** will actually be a problem as every **/** will split the value into multiple url elements. Sometimes even multiple **/** come up together in the output string

```
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16); //Create a random key. Keep it safe
$plaintext = "This is my Welcome Text";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
echo $ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );

//decrypt later....
$c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}
```

Output achieved:

> qe2EDPUqD1IhyCnpDs/8FjVWp2G3zFcCv7IZSMTa1/q1H61BBa+QAPAGQ8FbyohtT/IwK/DVhaEU7BG/ZtmBdjTX2tE6x9/jgyl62eeei5I=

How can I achieve a cipher text without any special characters?

Answer (score 2):

Don't just cram RAW data into a URL. Or anywhere else for that matter. Nearly everywhere you want to output data will have an encoding you should adhere to.

There's no such thing as "special characters", only incorrectly encoded data.

**Option 1:** Just URL-encode it. The encoder knows which characters are significant to the encoding, and how to properly escape them, and the client on the other side should intuitively know how to decode it.

```php
$data = "qe2EDPUqD1IhyCnpDs/8FjVWp2G3zFcCv7IZSMTa1/q1H61BBa+QAPAGQ8FbyohtT/IwK/DVhaEU7BG/ZtmBdjTX2tE6x9/jgyl62eeei5I=";
var_dump(urlencode($data));
```

Output:

```
string(124) "qe2EDPUqD1IhyCnpDs%2F8FjVWp2G3zFcCv7IZSMTa1%2Fq1H61BBa%2BQAPAGQ8FbyohtT%2FIwK%2FDVhaEU7BG%2FZtmBdjTX2tE6x9%2Fjgyl62eeei5I%3D"
```

**Option 2:** There is a URL-safe variant of base64 that replaces `+`, `=`, and `/`, but both client and server need to be aware of/implement it.

```php
function base64url_encode($bin) {
    return str_replace(['+', '/', '='], ['-', '_', ''], base64_encode($bin));
}

function base64url_decode($str) {
    return base64_decode(str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $str));
}

$data = "qe2EDPUqD1IhyCnpDs/8FjVWp2G3zFcCv7IZSMTa1/q1H61BBa+QAPAGQ8FbyohtT/IwK/DVhaEU7BG/ZtmBdjTX2tE6x9/jgyl62eeei5I=";
$bin = base64_decode($data);

var_dump(base64url_encode($bin));
```

Output:

```
string(107) "qe2EDPUqD1IhyCnpDs_8FjVWp2G3zFcCv7IZSMTa1_q1H61BBa-QAPAGQ8FbyohtT_IwK_DVhaEU7BG_ZtmBdjTX2tE6x9_jgyl62eeei5I"
```

Comment: Hi @Sammitch In method 1, is it safe to convert those symbols into entities, is this 100% safe approach and will always render correct data when I use url_decode? And in method 2, is it sure that we will not get '-' and '_' in the output of openssl_encrypt and base64_encode? Also, removing '=' from the resulting string is safe?

Comment: 1. Yes, and yes. 2. `-` and `_` were chosen for the variant because they aren't part of the original base64 alphabet. `=` are just padding characters as base64 technically outputs in blocks of 4 bytes. This is why you'll only ever see 1-3 of them at the very end. If the base64 decoder on the other side is picky the receiving end can easily add them back, but PHP's decoder doesn't care so we don't have to.